# Group list by year and sub group by month in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, arraylist, grouping

Let's say I have a list like this:

```
list = [["A",datetime.datetime(1985,8,31,0,0)], ["B",datetime.datetime(2014,4,3,0,0)], ["C",datetime.datetime(2014,4,4,0,0)],["D",datetime.datetime(2014,6,9,0,0)], ["E",datetime.datetime(2015,6,1,0,0)], ["F",datetime.datetime(2015,2,7,0,0)]]
```

How can I most elegantly group this by year and sub group by month to get this list output in Python such as:

```
newlist = [["A",datetime.datetime(1985,8,31,0,0)], [[["B",datetime.datetime(2014,4,3,0,0)], ["C",datetime.datetime(2014,4,4,0,0)]],["D",datetime.datetime(2014,6,9,0,0)]], [["E",datetime.datetime(2015,6,1,0,0)], ["F",datetime.datetime(2015,2,7,0,0)]]]
```

So the value are grouped by year and than by month and the order is preserve
I am importing datetime module in my code

```
import datetime
```

and applying strptime

```
kdate=year/month/day
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(kdate , "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Than I am saving date in a list. The list appears as above

Comment: Any reason why the singleton sublists aren't nested?

Comment: @schwobaseggl: they  are "grouped" by year and month

Answer (score 0):

By using **itertools.groupby** you can group by year then by month.

The expression is a little complex and require the initial list to be sorted before applying any groupby expression but it allows to get a decent result.

```
newlist = [[list(subgroup) for _, subgroup in groupby(group, key=lambda i: i[1].strftime("%m"))] for _, group in groupby(sorted(mylist, key=lambda i: i[1].strftime("%Y%m%d")), key=lambda i: i[1].strftime("%Y"))]
```

Initial list is sorted by year, month and day using the pattern CCYYMMDD.
Sorted list is then grouped by year.
Resulting list is eventually grouped by month.

That will return a 3-levels list composed of:

- Sublists enumerating every distinct year present in your initial list.
- Year sublists are composed of sublists enumerating every distinct month relative to the year.
- Month sublists are eventually composed of groups relative to both the month and the year. These lowest sublists are sorted by ascending day.

Here is the result got from your list:

```
[[[['A', datetime.datetime(1985, 8, 31, 0, 0)]]], [[['B', datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 3, 0, 0)], ['C', datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 4, 0, 0)]], [['D', datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 9, 0, 0)]]], [[['F', datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 7, 0, 0)]], [['E', datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 1, 0, 0)]]]]
```

It is not exactly what you are expecting. But the interest of this structure is it respects the hieharchy of days nested into months and months nested into years. It can be easily used as input for a loop structure (for example).

```
for year in newlist:
    for month in year:
        for day in month:
            # some code here.
```

Hope it can help.